# Storing multiple UNC paths for multiple processes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ssis, web-config

I'm creating an application that processes multiple files but puts the files in different locations. For example:

**\\Server\department\DEV\AppFolder\Process1**

**\\Server\department\DEV\AppFolder\Process2**

**\\Server\department\DEV\AppFolder\Process3**

**\\Server\department\DEV\AppFolder\Process4**

There will be 10 processes and each process has about 5 other sub-folders named similarly where related process files are dumped. Lets say they're named SubFolder1, SubFolder2, etc...

Would it be okay to save the UNC paths in a database. These paths are needed by an SSIS package as well as the application? The drawback is that if the DEV database is refreshed from production is that we'll have to update the values manually via a script.

I also thought about doing this:

**\\Server\department\#ENVIRONMENT#\AppFolder\Process4**

Where environment would be replaced by the application or the SSIS package when it gets the value from the database or creating an "Environment" column on this table and not needing to do any updates once configured. Setting an environment variable in the web.config and passing in the environment as a parameter to the SSIS package.

**Web.Config** is also an option but then 50 app settings would need to be configured in each build/release on TFS? And the SSIS package is left out. Although I could expose the paths required by SSIS via a web API as this is an intranet app with windows based authentication but I'm not sure if that's secure or okay.

What is the best or a better approach?

**Edit**: The SSIS package just needs the first subfolder in each process folder.

Comment: Why not `path = "\\Server\department\{0}\AppFolder\Process{1}"` then `string.Format(path, devEnv, process)`

Answer (score 0):

use a resource file to store the paths as string values instead of the database where it is overwritten or the web.config where it will cause bloat
The environment can be determined dynamically, one way ois to check the http server key for the site url aginst a live or dev web,config key

A less dicey spolution would be for Dev to write elsewhere else apart from the production directory